# Primefaces p:confirmDialog inside tabView

Tags: primefaces, dialog, confirm, tabview

I now have problem with using confirmDialog inside tabView.
Here is my confirmDialog

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
            styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
            styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

In the 1st tabView, I have a button with confirmation

```
<p:commandButton value="Import" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"
    update=":form:growl">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" />
</p:commandButton>
```

In the 2nd tabView, I have exactly that button.

And now my problem is: In the 1st tab, my confirmDialog have full text as I want: header and message, however in the 2nd tab, the header and message all become "null". Only button yes and no of confirmDialog still work. I don't know what is happening, please help me, how to make confirmDialog display full content in all tabView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work ok for me. See example below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>JSF User Dialog</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>This is a JSF view.</h3>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
            </h:form>
        </p:confirmDialog>

        <p:tabView id="tabView">

            <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab one ">
                <p:commandButton value="Import" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"
                    update=":form">
                    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab two">
                <p:commandButton value="Import" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"
                    update=":form">
                    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:tab>


        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: Tab 1 with dialog box]
[image: Tab 2 with dialog box]

It would be good if you post your full xhtml code so we can see what could be the problem there.

Comment: I got my problem. It's because of property  dynamic="true" of tabView. I just remove it

Comment: Glad that your problem is sorted :)

Answer (score 7):

p:confirm does not implement state saving, thus it loses its attributes' values after the first JSF lifecycle. It also evaluates EL only once at view build time.

## How to fix state saving.

You can extends PrimeFaces' `ConfirmBehavior`, implement `saveState`, `restoreState`, and override the original behavior in faces-config.xml by behavior-id `org.primefaces.behavior.ConfirmBehavior`. Then you'll be able to render and re-render p:confirm on subsequent requests.

## How to fix state saving and reevaluate EL bound attribute values.

You should create your own my:confirm, because you need a custom taghandler, and you can't substitute a taghandler of another taglibrary's tag in a non-ugly way.

**Create ConfirmBehavior.**

```java
package my;

import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.behavior.base.AbstractBehavior;
import org.primefaces.component.api.Confirmable;
import org.primefaces.json.JSONObject;

public class ConfirmBehavior extends AbstractBehavior {

    public final static String BEHAVIOR_ID = "my.ConfirmBehavior";

    @Override
    public String getScript(ClientBehaviorContext behaviorContext) {
        FacesContext context = behaviorContext.getFacesContext();
        UIComponent component = behaviorContext.getComponent();
        String source = component.getClientId(context);
        String headerText = JSONObject.quote(this.getHeader());
        String messageText = JSONObject.quote(this.getMessage());

        if (component instanceof Confirmable) {
            String script = "PrimeFaces.confirm({source:\"" + source + "\",header:" + headerText + ",message:"
                    + messageText + ",icon:\"" + getIcon() + "\"});return false;";
            ((Confirmable) component).setConfirmationScript(script);

            return null;
        } else {
            throw new FacesException("Component " + source + " is not a Confirmable. ConfirmBehavior can only be "
                    + "attached to components that implement org.primefaces.component.api.Confirmable interface");
        }
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return eval(PropertyKeys.header, null);
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        setLiteral(PropertyKeys.header, header);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return eval(PropertyKeys.message, null);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        setLiteral(PropertyKeys.message, message);
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return eval(PropertyKeys.icon, null);
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        setLiteral(PropertyKeys.icon, icon);
    }

    public enum PropertyKeys {
        header(String.class), message(String.class), icon(String.class);

        final Class<?> expectedType;

        PropertyKeys(Class<?> expectedType) {
            this.expectedType = expectedType;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Enum<?>[] getAllProperties() {
        return PropertyKeys.values();
    }

}
```

**Create ConfirmBehaviorHandler.**

```java
package my;

import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.BehaviorConfig;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttribute;

import org.primefaces.behavior.base.AbstractBehaviorHandler;

public class ConfirmBehaviorHandler extends AbstractBehaviorHandler<ConfirmBehavior> {

    private final TagAttribute header;
    private final TagAttribute message;
    private final TagAttribute icon;

    public ConfirmBehaviorHandler(BehaviorConfig config) {
        super(config);
        this.header = this.getAttribute(ConfirmBehavior.PropertyKeys.header.name());
        this.message = this.getAttribute(ConfirmBehavior.PropertyKeys.message.name());
        this.icon = this.getAttribute(ConfirmBehavior.PropertyKeys.icon.name());
    }

    @Override
    protected ConfirmBehavior createBehavior(FaceletContext ctx, String eventName) {
        Application application = ctx.getFacesContext().getApplication();
        ConfirmBehavior behavior = (ConfirmBehavior) application.createBehavior(ConfirmBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);

        setBehaviorAttribute(ctx, behavior, this.header, ConfirmBehavior.PropertyKeys.header.expectedType);
        setBehaviorAttribute(ctx, behavior, this.message, ConfirmBehavior.PropertyKeys.message.expectedType);
        setBehaviorAttribute(ctx, behavior, this.icon, ConfirmBehavior.PropertyKeys.icon.expectedType);

        return behavior;
    }

}
```

**Register ConfirmBehavior in faces-config.xml.**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <behavior>
        <behavior-id>my.ConfirmBehavior</behavior-id>
        <behavior-class>my.ConfirmBehavior</behavior-class>
    </behavior>

</faces-config>
```

**Register ConfirmBehaviorHandler in your taglibrary my.taglib.xml.**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <namespace>http://mycompany.ru/my</namespace>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>confirm</tag-name>
        <behavior>
            <behavior-id>my.ConfirmBehavior</behavior-id>
            <handler-class>my.ConfirmBehaviorHandler</handler-class>
        </behavior>
    </tag>

</facelet-taglib>
```

Now you can use my:confirm, just as you would use p:confirm, but with state saving and dynamic EL evaluation.

Comment: Seems like p:confirm is improved in PF 5.2.5: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/383

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the component. The proposed solution of removing the dynamic true works, but when we have to work in a dialog does not meet because the data are no longer updated automatically resulting in that the fields are blank.
If this happens you must perform the following action.
Ex:.

```
       <p:commandButton  style="font-size: 12px;width:30px;height:20px;"  icon="ui-icon-trash">
            <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Você realmente quer excluir o item de despacho?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
       </p:commandButton>
       <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
       <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" style="font-size: 12px;" closeOnEscape="true" widgetVar="confir">
            <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Sim" ajax="true"  type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"  style="font-size: 12px;">
                <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{tableExpedicao.excluiItem}" update="confirm" oncomplete="confir.hide()"> </p:ajax>
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" style="font-size: 12px;" oncomplete="confir.hide()"/>
     </p:confirmDialog>
```